# Keyboard is not shown up after came from android default contact page in my app

Tags: keyboard

I have one button called "Invite Paricipants". When i tap on it, my app will goes to android default contact page. After selecting contact, i am calculating the emails in it. If i found no email then, showing edit text to enter email. There i am using following code

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                editText.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        editText.requestFocus();
```

but keyboard is not showing up. How can i resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes he is right, after coming back the focus to `EditText` has been lost and by using `requestFocus` for `EditText` allows you to have focus and obviously pops up the Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You have to request input focus for `editText`.
To do this go to your interface definition xml and add:

`<requestFocus />`

Inside the definition for `editText`.